# Реализация класса граф<T> в c++

Tags: c++, классы, c++11, графы, класс

Попробовал реализовать класс граф T выдает ошибку:"NULL: идентификатор не найден"
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
template <class T>
class Graph;

template <class T>
class Vertex
{
private:
    T data;
    Vertex<T>* next;
public:
    friend class Graph<T>;
    Vertex(T dat, Vertex<T>* nex)
    {
         data = dat;  next = nex;
    }
};


template <class T>
class Graph
{
public:
    Vertex<T>* head;
    Graph() : head(NULL)
    {
    }



    void insert(T data)
    {
          Vertex<T>* ptr = new Vertex<T>(data, head);
          head = ptr;
    }
};
```

Comment: Если у Вас с++11 то вместо NULL пишите nullptr

Comment: `NULL` — это макрос, определённый в одном из следующих заголовочных файлов: `<cstddef>`, `<cstdlib>`, `<cstdio>`, `<cstring>`, `<ctime>`, `<cwchar>`, `<clocale>`, а также в их `.h`-аналогах. Для использования `NULL` необходимо подключить хотя бы один из этих заголовочных файлов. См.: [NULL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/NULL).